# Can you help make me this picture in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I tried using some of the code in Tikz but I don't get the magnetic fields to work (third plot in https://tikz.net/magnetic_field_loop/)

[image]

This is the code that doesn't show the magnetic fields:

```
    % Author: Izaak Neutelings (March 2020)
    \documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amsmath} % for \dfrac
    \usepackage{physics}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
    \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
    \usepackage{pst-magneticfield}
    \usepackage[outline]{contour} % glow around text
    \usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes} % for pic (angle labels)
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
    \tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \colorlet{Ecol}{orange!90!black}
    \colorlet{EcolFL}{orange!80!black}
    \colorlet{veccol}{green!45!black}
    \colorlet{projcol}{blue!70!black}
    \colorlet{EFcol}{red!60!black}
    \colorlet{Bcol}{violet!90}
    \colorlet{Bcol1}{violet!80!blue!90}
    \colorlet{Bcol2}{violet!80!red!90}
    \colorlet{BFcol}{red!70!black}
    \colorlet{veccol}{green!45!black}
    \colorlet{Icol}{blue!70!black}
    \colorlet{Ampcol}{green!60!black!70}
    \tikzstyle{BField}=[->,thick,Bcol]
    \tikzstyle{current}=[->,Icol,thick]
    \tikzstyle{force}=[->,thick,BFcol]
    \tikzstyle{vector}=[->,thick,veccol]
    \tikzstyle{velocity}=[->,very thick,vcol]
    \tikzstyle{metal}=[top color=black!15,bottom color=black!25,middle color=black!20,shading angle=10]
    \tikzstyle{darkmetal}=[top color=black!40,bottom color=black!70,middle color=black!30,shading angle=10]
    \tikzstyle{lightmetal}=[thin,black!20,top color=black!3,bottom color=black!6,middle color=black!1,shading angle=10]
    \tikzstyle{proj}=[projcol!80,line width=0.08] %very thin
    \tikzstyle{area}=[draw=veccol,fill=veccol!80,fill opacity=0.6]
    \tikzstyle{measline}=[{Latex[length=3]}-{Latex[length=3]}]
    \tikzset{
      BFieldLine/.style={thick,Bcol,decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{latex}}},
                                    postaction={decorate}},
      BFieldLine/.default=0.5,
      Ampcurve/.style={Ampcol,decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{latex}}},
                              postaction={decorate}},
      Ampcurve/.default=0.55,
      pics/Bin/.style={
        code={
          \def\R{0.12}
          \draw[pic actions,line width=0.6,#1,fill=white] % ,thick
            (0,0) circle (\R) (-135:.75*\R) -- (45:.75*\R) (-45:.75*\R) -- (135:.75*\R);
      }},
      pics/Bout/.style={
        code={
          \def\R{0.12}
          \draw[pic actions,line width=0.6,#1,fill=white] (0,0) circle (\R);
          \fill[pic actions,#1] (0,0) circle (0.3*\R);
      }},
      pics/Bin/.default=Bcol,
      pics/Bout/.default=Bcol,
    }
    \tikzstyle{measure}=[fill=white,midway,outer sep=2]
    %\newcommand\arrmark[1]{mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{latex}}}
    %\def\myarrmark#1{mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{latex}}}
    \contourlength{1.4pt}
    
    % RING SHADING
    \makeatletter
    \pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{ring}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}%
    {rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
    rgb(0.719cm)=(1,1,1);
    color(0.72cm)=(tikz@ball);
    rgb(0.9cm)=(1,1,1)}
    \tikzoption{ring color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{ring}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
    \makeatother
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    
    % LOOP CURRENT 2D
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      
      % VARIABLE
      \def\Rin{1.1}
      \def\Rout{1.2}
      \def\dphi{15}
      \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
      \coordinate (P) at (0:\Rin);
      
      % WIRE
      \draw[shading=ring, ring color=black!60,even odd rule]
        (0,0) circle (\Rin) circle (\Rout);
      %\fill[metal]
      %  (\Rin,\Rout) -- (0,\Rout) -- 
      %  (0,\Rin) -- (\Rin,\Rin);
      
      % DARK
      \draw[darkmetal] %,even odd rule]
        (-\dphi/2:\Rin) arc (-\dphi/2:\dphi/2:\Rin) -- (\dphi/2:\Rout) arc (\dphi/2:-\dphi/2:\Rout) -- cycle;
      \draw[darkmetal] %,even odd rule]
        (180-\dphi/2:\Rin) arc (180-\dphi/2:180+\dphi/2:\Rin) -- (180+\dphi/2:\Rout) arc (180+\dphi/2:180-\dphi/2:\Rout) -- cycle;
      
      % VECTORS
      \draw[force,-{Latex[length=4,width=3]}]
        (-\dphi/2:{(\Rin+\Rout)/2}) -- (\dphi/2:{(\Rin+\Rout)/2}) node[midway,above right=-1] {$\dd\vb*{\ell}_1$};
      \draw[force,-{Latex[length=4,width=3]}]
        (180-\dphi/2:{(\Rin+\Rout)/2}) -- (180+\dphi/2:{(\Rin+\Rout)/2}) node[midway,below left=-1] {$\dd\vb*{\ell}_2$};
      \draw[current,domain=0:40,samples=10]
        (-70:1.15*\Rout) arc (-70:-30:1.15*\Rout) node[midway,below] {$I$};
        
      % MAGNETIC FIELD
      %\draw[BField] (X) -- (BY) node[right=-1] {$\dd{\vb{B}_\perp}$};
      \pic at (0, 0.13*\Rin) {Bout={Bcol1}};
      \pic at (0,-0.13*\Rin) {Bout={Bcol2}};
      \pic at ( 1.8*\Rin, 0.13*\Rin) {Bin={Bcol1}};
      \pic at ( 1.8*\Rin,-0.13*\Rin) {Bout={Bcol2}};
      \pic at (-1.8*\Rin, 0.13*\Rin) {Bout={Bcol1}};
      \pic at (-1.8*\Rin,-0.13*\Rin) {Bin={Bcol2}};
      \node[Bcol1,right=2] at (0, 0.15*\Rin) {$\vb{B}_1$};
      \node[Bcol2,left=1] at (0,-0.15*\Rin) {$\vb{B}_2$};
      \node[Bcol1,right=2] at (1.8*\Rin, 0.15*\Rin) {$\vb{B}_1$};
      \node[Bcol2,right=2] at (1.8*\Rin,-0.15*\Rin) {$\vb{B}_2$};
      \node[Bcol1,left=1] at (-1.8*\Rin, 0.15*\Rin) {$\vb{B}_1$};
      \node[Bcol2,left=1] at (-1.8*\Rin,-0.15*\Rin) {$\vb{B}_2$};
      
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
    % LOOP CURRENT 3D
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{100}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,tdplot_main_coords]
      
      % VARIABLE
      \def\t{0.01}
      \def\Rin{0.7}
      \def\Rout{0.74}
      \def\Bpara{0.26}
      \def\Bperp{0.24}
      \def\rvec{1.3}
      \def\thetavec{50}
      \def\phivec{70}
      \def\dtheta{10}
      \def\dphi{15}
      \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
      \coordinate (P) at ({\Rin*cos(\phivec)},{\Rin*sin(\phivec)},{1.4*\t*cos(\phivec)});
      \coordinate (P0) at (0:0.96*\Rin);
      \coordinate (X) at (0,0,1.0*\Rin);
      \coordinate (BY) at ({\Bpara*cos(\phivec)},{\Bpara*sin(\phivec)},1.0*\Rin);
      \coordinate (BX) at (0,0,1.0*\Rin+\Bperp);
      \coordinate (B) at ({\Bpara*cos(\phivec)},{\Bpara*sin(\phivec)},1.0*\Rin+\Bperp);
      
      % WIRE
      \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-0.5*\Rin);
      \draw[shading=ring, ring color=black!60,domain=0:360,samples=120,even odd rule]
        plot ({\Rin*cos(\x)},{\Rin*sin(\x)},{\t*cos(\x)})
        plot ({\Rout*cos(\x)},{\Rout*sin(\x)},{-\t*cos(\x)});
      \draw[dashed] (0,0,1.39*\Rin) -- (0,0,0);
      
      % DARK
      \draw[darkmetal,domain=0:\dphi,samples=20] %,even odd rule]
        (P) --
        plot ({\Rin*cos(\phivec+\x)},{\Rin*sin(\phivec+\x)},{\t*cos(\phivec+\x)}) to[out=60,in=80]
        (\phivec+\dphi:\Rout) --
        plot ({\Rout*cos(\phivec+\dphi-\x)},{\Rout*sin(\phivec+\dphi-\x)},{-\t*cos(\phivec+\dphi-\x)}) to[out=90,in=40]
        cycle;
      \draw[dashed] (O) -- (P);
      \draw[dashed] (O) -- (P0);
      
      % VECTORS
      \draw[vector] (P) -- (X) node[left=3,below left=2] {$\vb{r}$};
      \draw[force,-{Latex[length=4,width=3]}]
        (P) --++ ({-0.3*\Rin*sin(\phivec+\dphi/2)},{0.3*\Rin*cos(\phivec+\dphi/2)},0) node[above left=-2] {$\vb*{\ell}$};
      \draw[dashed,very thin] (BY) -- (B) -- (BX);
      \draw[BField] (X) -- (BY) node[right=-1] {$\dd{\vb{B}_\perp}$};
      \draw[BField] (X) -- (BX) node[left=-1] {$\dd{\vb{B}_\parallel}$};
      \draw[BField] (X) -- (B) node[above right=-1] {$\dd{\vb{B}}$};
      \draw[current,domain=0:40,samples=10]
        (-40:1.15*\Rout) arc (-40:-10:1.15*\Rout) node[midway,below] {$I$};
      % plot ({1.1*\Rout*cos(-20+\x)},{1.1*\Rout*sin(-20+\x)},0) 
      
      % ANGLES
      %\tdplotdrawarc[->]{(O)}{0.29*\rvec}{0}{\phivec}
      %  {anchor=north}{$\phi$}
      %\tdplotdrawarc[->]{(O)}{0.4*\rvec}{\phivec}{\phivec+\dphi}
      %  {above=0.5,anchor=123}{\contour{white}{$\dd{\phi}$}}
      \tdplotdrawarc[->]{(O)}{0.30*\Rin}{0}{\phivec}
        {below=-1,scale=1}{\contour{white}{$\phi$}}
      \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
      \tdplotdrawarc[->,tdplot_rotated_coords]{(P)}{0.2*\Rin}{-90}{atan(1.1)-90}
        {above=2,left=-1,scale=1}{$\theta$}
      \tdplotdrawarc[->,tdplot_rotated_coords]{(X)}{0.2*\Rin}{0}{atan(1.1)}
        {right=2,above=-1,scale=1}{\contour{white}{$\theta$}}
      
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
    % LOOP MAGNETIC FIELD
    \def\xmax{3.6}
    \def\ymax{3.5}
    \contourlength{1.0pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shift={(\xmax+0.024,\ymax+0.024)}]
      \message{Loop start. ^^J}
      \def\R{1}
      \begin{scope} %[shift={(3,3)}]
        \clip (-\xmax,-\ymax) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
        \begin{pspicture*}(-\xmax,-\ymax)(\xmax,\ymax)
          \psframe[linecolor=white](-\xmax,-\ymax)(\xmax,\ymax)
          \psmagneticfield[
              N=1,R=\R,L=2, %-0.005,
              nL=5,pointsB=200,
              nS=0,%numSpires=10,pointsS=500,
              linewidth=1.0pt,linecolor=Bcol,drawSelf=false
            ](-\xmax,-\ymax)(\xmax,\ymax)
        \end{pspicture*}
      \end{scope}
      \draw[metal] (-\R,0.122*\R) -| (\R,-0.122*\R) -| cycle;
      \pic[scale=1] at (-\R,0) {Bout={Icol}};
      \pic[scale=1] at ( \R,0) {Bin={Icol}};
      \draw[current] (-0.6*\R,-0.01*\R) arc (-94:-86:{0.6*\R/sin(4)})
        node[midway,below=0.8,scale=1.8] {\contour{white}{$I$}};
      \message{Loop done. ^^J}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the code does not create the ring the appropriate magnetic field lines.

I would to try to use this code to make the screenshot picture at the very beginning of this post. can you help me? please.

https://tikz.net/files/magnetic_field_loop-003.png

Comment: What DOES your posted code produce? Please add that screenshot(s) to your question. // Am I right, you just copied code without understanding much of it?

Comment: I added the code and the picture and why it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

A first approach (to the linked image) that probably will need some fine tuning.

We need the `decorations.markings` library form Ti*k*Z to place the arrows along the lines. We need to draw a few ellipses too. For this I suggest a couple of `\foreach` loops. Add a `\clip` and we are done.

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset
{% styles for arrows and borders
  field line/.style={
    magenta,
    decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.1 with {\arrow[scale={-#1}]{latex}},
                         mark=at position 0.4 with {\arrow[scale={-#1}]{latex}},
                         mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow[scale={-#1}]{latex}},
                         mark=at position 0.9 with {\arrow[scale={-#1}]{latex}}},
    postaction={decorate}
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[left color=gray] (-1,-0.2) arc (-90:90:0.2) -- (1,0.2) arc (90:270:0.2) -- cycle;
\clip (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
\foreach\i in {-1,1}
{
  \draw[blue] (\i,0) circle (0.2);
  \draw[blue] (1,0) ++ (0.1,0.1*\i) --++ (-0.2,-0.2*\i);
}
\fill[blue] (-1,0) circle (0.2mm);
\draw[thick,blue,-latex] (-0.7,0) -- (0.7,0) node[pos=0.55,below] {$I$};
\draw[field line=1] (0,3) -- (0,-3);
\foreach\i in {0.2,0.4,0.6} \foreach\j in {-1,1}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\a{0.7/\i}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\b{0.9*\a}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\c{sqrt(\a*\a-\b*\b)}
  \draw[field line=\j] ({\j*(\a+\i)},0) ellipse ({\a} and \b);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]